# .htaccess duplicate static content loading

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, static, subdomain

I've made a sub-domain for static content (static.site.com) and I have the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.site.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|css|js|txt|ico|pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.static.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Everything is loading fine, but in firebug i have two lines for every file with rewrited path:

```
http://www.site.com/images/image.png (301 Moved Permanently)
```

and

```
http://www.static.site.com/images/image.png (304 Not Modified)
```

How can I prevent loading my content from main domain. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I prevent loading my content from main domain. Thanks.

Contents don't load from your main domain. when you request `http://www.site.com/images/image.png` server will send you `http://www.static.site.com/images/image.png`.

Note: as I understand your files are in subdirectory in main domain. so you can change document root of your subdomain.

Comment: I just want to rewrite all content's paths without showing 301 redirect in firebug.

Comment: @andrew use sub-domain instead of main-domain. otherwise it will send 301 status code!

Comment: That's what i'm trying to do. I want to change automatically all static content paths from main-domain to sub-domain.

Comment: @andrew  You should change your static contents ,Otherwise , If you use main-domain it will send redirect header to your browser!

Comment: So, i did that way. Manually changed all paths. Not what i what i wanted, but it works.